# Create an array from database results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create an array from a database query. I want to select 10 random questions by their ID, and put them into an Array, JUST the ID, i do not want it to be like `[0]=>array('1'),[1]=>array('2')`, I would like to to simply be, `array('1','2','3')` etc.

After they are in the array i would like to be able to check if the id is in the array

Comment: `array([0]=>'1',[1]=>'2',[2]=>'3')` is the same as `array('1','2','3')`.  You can check this with `print_r(array('1','2','3'))`.  As for checking what's in the array, have a look at [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: If you create array('1','2','3') you will get [0]=>'1',[1]=>'2', [3]=>'3'. I recommend to get more information about PHP

Comment: he will get as result [['id'=>1],['id'=>3],['id'=>4],['id'=>5]] NOT [0=>1,1=>3,...]

Comment: @ItayMoav I don't really think that your edit is what the OP was thinking about.

Comment: @tsabz regardless, this is the output of any query u do against DB unless u use the method I described below.

Comment: @ItayMoav I just think that he was priting the result he had, not the way to build the array.

Comment: @tsabz - well, the OP has the ability to re-edit my edit. If I was wrong, let him undo it. But, it is more than likely I was right. Otherwise, his question has no meaning.

Comment: I agree with Marcio Simao, I just think he misunderstood how array, and more generically PHP, work. But let's wait for some clarification ;)

Comment: @tsabz, Make mine your words, i think he is a beginner in PHP and is confused about how to use the language. Even our comments he doesn't answered. Google could help him a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

If u use the PDO php extension, use the http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php to retrieve the values of the column as one-dim array.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO([dsn], [username], [password]);
    $sql = "
        SELECT ID 
        FROM [tablename] 
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 10
    ";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement) {
        //error handling here
    }
    $result = $statement->execute();
    if (!$result) {
        //error handling here
    $array = array();
    while (list($id) = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $array[] = $id;
    }
    $statement = NULL;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //error handling here
}
```

This should leave an enumerated array of the ID's